# Mixing different files with different classes

Tags: memoir, pdfpages, amsart, multiple-files

I am currently writing a project which will be composed of a main file, and several chapters.

The main file is based on `memoir`, but the chapters are all `amsart`.

Currently I am manually changing the page numbers in the chapter files, and using `pdfpages` to stitch in the .pdf files. This has the effect that the links are removed.

Is there a better solution that will allow me to preserve the links? If not, is there a way to combine the TOCs from all the files, and preferably with the internal hyperlinks?

Comment: The document class is a property of the (whole) document, not of single chapters. What do you mean by the chapters all being "amsart"? In a document (including all the files that are `\input` or `\include`d) there can only be a single `\documentclass` line near the beginning, which will determine the document class of the whole document.

Comment: I usually just use `docmute` and then `\input` or `\include` the files. `docmute` changes `\input` and friends such that it ignores any preamble in the included file. This of course meants that any needed packages or macros from the included docs have to be added to the main doc. So far I has worked fine.

Comment: @daleif -- if the op tries this and it works, this is the answer.  i am quite interested in learning the outcome in this case.

Comment: @barbarabeeton we have a book in the works at Springer that was made this way. We cleaned the initial 15 chapters (from 15 different sets of authors), common macros was gathered in a style file (uncommon macros was resolved in each chapter in order for them not to interfere). In addition a special style file was prepared that contains the label data from each chapter. Each chapter was given just article class and these two packages and then could be compiled on their own (and thus updatable by the authors) and we could collect everything into the book by just including the authors files as it

Comment: As the `amsart` document class doesn't provide a `\chapter` command, what does it mean that "the chapters are all `amsart`"?

Comment: @Mico: There is a `\chapter` "preamble" and then I use `pdfpages` to smash the document into the .pdf file.

Comment: @barbara: Actually, I think that I can make that suggestion work. All the produced .pdf files have fairly similar preambles, most of which is also used in the main `memoir` file. So I think this might work. I'll give it a shot. I'll update when I have results.

Comment: @daleif: That suggestion might work, considering that most files have fairly similar preambles. I'll update in a couple of days once I have tried that. Thanks!

Comment: @Inkblot - Is the directive `\chapter{preamble}` part of the `memoir` document class, or is it part of an `amsart` document class?

Comment: @Mico: No, I meant I have a sort of "front matter" before I smash each chapter into the pdf. I meant preamble in that sense of the word.

Comment: @Inkblot - I'm afraid I really don't understand your document's setup. Maybe somebody else will.

Comment: @Mico: There's a skeleton of `memoir`, it includes some abstract and some basic TOC. Then each chapter begins as you would normally begin a chapter with `memoir`, with a first page detailing the file that would follow. Then using `pdfpages` I smash the `amsart`-compiled pdf in. Is that clearer?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Unfortunately, using `docmute` completely ignores the `amsart` and formats all the chapters with the same ol' `memoir` design. This is to be expected, of course, if we think closely about what it means that the preamble is ignored... :(

Comment: @Inkblot -- well, it was worth a try; thanks for the update.  have you given peter wilson's `combine` suggestion a try?  i'm thinking about how to "preserve" the links and tocs, to be available if you have to use `pdfpages`  i have some ideas, but they'll involve rerunning the articles on your end (with new page numbers), as well as some other work, salvaging material from `.toc` and `.aux` files.  this will most likely only permit `\pageref`.  would that be acceptable?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I submitted my dissertation already, but I'd be happy to hear about your suggestions. (As for as page numbers, the articles are already being recompiled with "correct page numbers"...)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `combine` package but I have no idea if it will work in your case.